# Optional after mapping

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

I have a simple code in which I try to split numbers into digits:

```
for n in 10...12
{
    let numberIntoString = String(n)
    let splitNumber = Array(numberIntoString)
    let charIntoString = splitNumber.map {String($0)}
    let numberIntoInteger = charIntoString.map {Int($0)}

    print(numberIntoInteger)   
}
```

and the output is:

```
[Optional(1), Optional(0)]
[Optional(1), Optional(1)]
[Optional(1), Optional(2)]
```

I did some research about "Optional" and find out that this term has something to do with wrapping/unwrapping value but to understand this fully I need someone to explain me this on my own code. So, my questions are: Why optional value appeared in my code and how to get rid of this unexpected output?
Also, I would like to know is there any way to write this code "better" (i.e. more readable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
let numberIntoInteger = charIntoString.map {Int($0)}
```

produces an optional. This is because converting `String` to `Int` (at `Int($0)`) might fail if the `String` provided is not a number. For example, `"abcde"` is not a number and cannot be converted to an `Int`. Therefore, `nil` will be returned. This is completely expected, not unexpected as you say, the `Int` initializer is designed like this.

You can get rid of the Optional value with implicit unwrapping as follows:

```
let numberIntoInteger = charIntoString.map {Int($0)!}
```

Note the `!` after the initializer. This will remove the optional. However, if the value is really `nil`, your program will crash. In your case, that should never happen as `n` should only be an `Int`.

You have another choice: Use `flatMap` **Note that this is deprecated in Xcode 9.3 Beta, use `compactMap` instead**

```
let numberIntoInteger = charIntoString.flatMap {Int($0)}
```

Comment: Or use a `flatMap`, which will only return the non-nil results.

Comment: [Thankfully, you seem to be wrong](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/replacing-flatmap-with-compactmap/), `compactMap` replaces `flatMap` entirely for this use case.

Comment: @OscarApeland Sorry I was confused. I've removed the comment and updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

An Optional can be seen as a "box" which can either contain the `value` or `nil`.

Some operations will return directly the value (since it does not have the possibility to be `nil`). This is the case of:

`String(n)`

However, some other operations will return that `box` (an Optional) because there is the possibility it is `nil`. This is the case of:

`Int($0)`

For instance, if you try `Int("")` you will get `nil`.

**Solution for your example**

A possible way to make your code more readable (and get rid of these Optionals) could be:

```
for n in 10...12
{
    let numberIntoString = String(n)
    let numberIntoInteger = numberIntoString.flatMap{Int(String($0))}

    print(numberIntoInteger)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is already answered – the `Int(*string*)` initializer returns an optional – this is a suggestion to get rid of the optional stuff.

The code does some math to split the digits (of course it works only for values from 0 to 99)

```
for n in 10...12
{
    let numberIntoInteger = [n / 10, n % 10]
    print(numberIntoInteger)
}
```